# Download de arquivos grandes PHP?

Tags: php, download, google-drive-api

Com o seguinte código, obtenho um arquivo armazenado no Google Drive:

```
$response = $service->files->get("id-do-meu-arquivo", array('alt' => 'media'));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

A variável `$content`, agora contem o arquivo que devo baixar, mudando os headers da página, o arquivo pode ser baixado, como por exemplo:

```
header("Content-type: mimeType");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = test.formato");
echo $content;
```

Enquanto o arquivo for pequeno, o código acima não será problema, porém quando preciso baixar um arquivo grande, obtenho erros e etc... A  página demora mais tempo para carregar (muito mais) e depois o usuário ainda tem que esperar o download, tornando-o inútil. Uma vez que eu pretendo chamar tal página através uma requisição `AJAX`, quais são as soluções que eu posso usar? E como posso obter informações como quanto falta para o arquivo terminar de baixar e etc..

Comment: certamente nos retornos da API deve conter as informações, vc teria o link pra eu dar uma olhada na documentação da api?

Comment: É a API de Google Drive, https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads